# dynamically support multiple SSL sites for one IP address

Tags: apache, ssl, dynamic, restart, tomcat8

For a web application running on Tomcat, to support multiple SSL sites on one Ip address, I like to add Apache in front of Tomcat.

Is it possible for user to upload its own SSL certificate and configure it dynamically without server restart?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot 
        ServerName

        SSLCertificateFile 
        SSLCertificateKeyFile
        SSLCACertificateFile
        SSLEngine on
    </VirtualHost>
```

For apache, the SSL configuration above needs to be added into apache conf file,
and requires server restart. Server restart is not acceptable because there will be many users on the same server.  Any solution?

Thanks for help.

Comment: A service httpd reload may be sufficient enough without actually taking the service down for a second or two.

Comment: If there are thousands of active users to configure SSL for their own sites, is it a good approach? The configuration file may corrupt if written concurrently by many users. Thanks